# How to load python modules on CentOS 7?

Tags: python

Hello. I am using CentOS-7. As you all, know CentOS-7's default installed python is 2.7.5. So I've installed python 3.4 by yum from epel repository. Now in terminal, "python" runs python 2.7.5 and "python3.4" runs python 3.4.

This is good. But the problem is...Today I've downloaded mysql connector for python from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/), and installed using yum. After that, When I try to import module in python 3.4, below error had occurred.

```
Import Error: No module named 'mysql'
```

But in python 2.7.5, that module import properly.

What should I do to import that module in python 3.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install via `pip`, it's installing for the specific/default Python version. So when you installed mysql, it installed to 2.7.5. Use `pip3.4` or `pip3` to also install it for Py3.x.

Edit: Since you're not doing it via pip, the module you're downloading - you need to download and install again for the correct Python version. They have different installers listed per platform, by bitness (or source which is platform independent) & Pyversion.

Comment: Thank you, "aneroid". I solved the problem by using "pip3.4" command!

Comment: Welcome. Also, you can refer to users with the `@` sign, so rather than "user", use `@user`.

Answer (score 1):

The module you install from yum depends on the current python version.
So first download virtualenv which contains your required python version (in your case https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ).

After that activate this virtualenvironment like this -

Go to the folder where you installed virtualenv from terminal.

Type source virtualenv/bin/activate.

After this run yum install command for your desired mysql connector.

This will download the mysql connector which is compatible with python 3.4.

Comment: Thank you "majin" for guide of virtualenv. I solved the problem by using pip. I have a plan to change my python GUI application from PyQt to PySide. In this situation, virtualenv will be great solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You reinstall it again either from a package (not the *same* package, a different one) or by building it from source for 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

1. download [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and set the python3.4 environment
2. download related module in this isolated environment